# Call a method by clicking a link that was created dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, hyperlink

Is it possible to create a link in ASP.NET C# dynamically that when clicked calls a method? The link will be created from code behind to display on a webpage. For example a linkbutton or button or hyperlink created dynamically with text="click here". When clicked, it calls a server side `protected void getMethod()`. No javascripts thank you.

Comment: In current state post is way too broad for SO - you may want to narrow down where you want to create the link (server side, client side, webbrowser control) and what frameworks you are targeting on server and client side of HTML (plus if you are hosting browser yourself - what control do you use).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're looking for.  You want to be sure to create the controls in Page_Init rather than Page_Load to ensure events are triggered properly.  Here's a basic example of creating the link dynamically with your method attached. In the example, I just add a LinkButton to a placeholder with a simple method that updates an existing label on the page.

ASP:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTest" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbLink = new LinkButton();

    lbLink.Text = "Click Here!";
    lbLink.Click += new EventHandler(getMethod);

    phTest.Controls.Add(lbLink);
}

protected void getMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Hi!";
}
```

Is this about what you're looking for?  Or is there more to it?

Comment: This looks very much like it. Great. Your code works, the link is created by code behind and it calls the method. Very grateful!